# Url exception in Scala

Tags: scala, url, exception

This codes works but throws `java.net.MalformedURLException`

```
val content = Source.fromURL("urladdress")
```

How to surround it with the `try-catch` block if I need the `content` value outside the block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A more functional approach is to use util.Try.

```
val contentT = Try(Source.fromURL(url))
```

This will give you a Try object that you can use map or fold functions on to use the content.

You then use the content as

```
for (content <- contentT) {
   // do something with content
}
```

And handle exceptions using recover

```
contentT recover {
  case e: MalformedURLException => // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `scala.util.Try` which returns the result in  `Success` or `Failure` case class. Then pattern match on this to get the result.

```
scala> val content = Try(Source.fromURL("urladdress"))
content: scala.util.Try[scala.io.BufferedSource] = Failure(java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: urladdress)
```